# How can i achieve this complex route in codeigniter

Tags: php, codeigniter

i want achieve complex route in codeigniter `$route['(:any)/(:any)/quiz/(:num)'] = "quiz/get_quiz/$1$2$3";` 
that is localhost/*/*/quiz/*. Thanks for your help.

Comment: try `$route['(:any)/(:any)/quiz/(:num)'] = "$1/$2/quiz/get_quiz/$3";`

Comment: it is not working

Comment: all 3 parameters are required or also optional??@KrishnaSatya

Comment: they are required

Answer (score 1):

I got it working by doing it like this

```
$route['(:any)/(:any)/quiz/(:num)'] = "quiz/get_quiz/$1/$2/$3"
```